# Secrets Detection in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having some troubles understanding how to activate Secrets Detection in Gitlab CI/CD.
I created a new NodeJS Express from template and then i activated auto-devops from **Settings > CI/CD** and checked the checkbox **Default to Auto Devops pipeline** under the Auto Devops Menu. After that i opened the app.js file in the project folder and inserted a variable that looks like a key-value. Here's the piece of code where i inserted the line:

```
...
var app = express();

var key = "api-12321321321321321";

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
...
```

After committing the changes i expected the pipeline to fail because of the leak of the secret. Here's an images that shows that secret dection passed.
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to make so that the pipeline reports the error?

Answer (score 5):

This behavior confused me as well when I first tried it out.

However, it seems that GitLab did this on purpose. Here is what the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/) says:

[image: gitlab documentation]

So with a free or premium account, you can just use this reporter, but you won't see any results, unless you download the JSON report.

Also, there is NO mention that the job will fail. This is just our expectation.

However, there are reasons why this makes sense, especially for a paid version of GitLab. In an MR, you want to know if there are any vulnerabilities in your code. However, not all reports are accurate. So you may get what is known as a false positive. Or, the reported issue is very generic and your software is not affected.

However, if you are on a free/premium account, this feature is almost useless, as nobody will go to the job and manually inspect it.

The only workaround would be to override the `secret_detection` job, parse the gl-secret-detection-report.json, check if it passed or failed and decide to PASS or FAIL the JOB.

Comment: Does anyone already written an extended job that will fail? I mean, the native job is pretty useless if it's succeeding no matter what.

Comment: @halloei - I am working toward a solution. I will keep you posted here.

Comment: I came up with the following solution: https://gist.github.com/halloei/8ea4f1763f16a426f86a56bcf6a97333 Looking forward to yours!

Comment: @halloei I was looking at something similar. However, it would be great to avoid so much config duplication.

Comment: If we want to check all the commits in the MR branch, we should add this for now: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/368897#workaround

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier with [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#configuration-tool-for-secret-detection) (May 2021, **Ultimate only**):

> ### Configuration tool for Secret Detection
>
> Following in the footsteps of the [GitLab SAST configuration tool](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/index.html#configure-sast-in-the-ui) we are adding support for Secret Detection on the Security Configuration page.
> We believe that [security is a team effort](https://about.gitlab.com/direction/secure/#security-is-a-team-effort), and this configuration experience makes it easier for non-CI experts to get started with [GitLab Secret Detection](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/).
>
> The tool helps a user create a merge request to enable Secret Detection scanning while leveraging best configuration practices like using the GitLab-managed [`SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml).
> The Configuration tool can create a new `.gitlab-ci.yml` file if one does not exist or update existing simple GitLab CI files, allowing the tool to be used with projects that already have GitLab CI setup.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_12/secret_config_button_13_12.png -- Configuration tool for Secret Detection]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/configuration/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4496).

---

See [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#additional-secret-detection-pattern-support) (November 2021, for all tiers)

> ### Additional Secret Detection pattern support
>
> We’ve updated the GitLab Secret Detection scanner to detect 47 new ‘well-identifiable’ secret patterns for widely used applications. This brings the GitLab Secret Detection detection up to over 90 detectable patterns.
>
> If you are a SaaS application vendor and your app generates secret tokens with well-identifiable patterns, and you’d like GitLab to be able to detect them, please add your regex pattern and a few invalid sample tokens [in a comment on this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345453) and we’ll get them added to GitLab Secret Detection.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_5/secret-detection.png -- Additional Secret Detection pattern support]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/#supported-secrets) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/340002).

---

[GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#secret-detection-updates) (July 2023) adds, this time for *all* tiers:

> ### Secret Detection updates
>
> We regularly release updates to the GitLab Secret Detection analyzer. During the GitLab 16.2 milestone, we:
>
> - Added [GitLab-managed detection rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/#detected-secrets) for:
>
>   - OpenAI API keys.
>   - CircleCI Personal and Project access tokens. Thanks to [`@nathanwfish`](https://gitlab.com/nathanwfish) for this community contribution.
> - Improved performance of rules that use the `keywords` optimization.
> - Fixed [an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/358073) where Secret Detection results created permalinks to the wrong location in the repository.
>
> See the [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v514) for further details.
>
> If you [use the GitLab-managed Secret Detection template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/#enable-secret-detection) ([`Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml)) and run GitLab 16.0 or higher, you automatically receive these updates.
> To remain on a specific version of any analyzer and prevent automatic updates, you can [pin its version](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/#pinning-to-specific-analyzer-version).
>
> For previous changes, see [the most recent Secret Detection update](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#secret-detection-updates).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/) and [Issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/#vulnerability-scanner-maintenance).

Comment: this is only available on ULTIMATE though

Comment: @EvertonArakaki The first part ("tool for Secret Detection") is for Ultimate indeed. The second part ("Additional Secret Detection pattern support") is for all tiers. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score -1):

GitLab has a full post about setting this up in a pipeline: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/

**EDIT:**

The given instructions are a bit unclear:

You need to add the `include` tag at "root-level" of your configuration.

**Example**

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

image: node:latest

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"
        - npm install typescript
        - yarn run build
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing"

include:
    - template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml
```

The secret detection will run in the test stage:
[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZNQ6.png)

Comment: still it does not answer the question because the pipeline succeeds if there is a secret in the code